# how to tell a tree panel to render a record again?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I change some values of a tree node programmatically and want to show the `Ext.tree.Panel` the new value.

With `set()` I get the record "dirty" but somehow this isn't enough to trigger the renderer to rerender the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[beginEdit()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-beginEdit)** and **[endEdit()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-endEdit)** instead. That should trigger the responsible events

Comment: Thank you. I saw those methods and thought they were something like "locks" while editing nodes. Added them at the beginning and end of every modifying model-method and everything works :)

Comment: @da_b0uncer Not all, they are exactly for such use cases :) They will also prevent the dirty mark until you call `endEdit()` so that nothing will happens until you're with the edit.

Comment: I see... I made some `get()` and `set()` calls to change the image of a row in a column, because I didn't know about this. Now I probably can rely only on the renderer to do this.